# Can I add a common reference path in an MSBuild target/project file?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, target, assembly-reference-path

I'm trying to write a custom project (targets?) file that is to be included in several projects.

For example, inside all of my .csproj and .vbproj files I have:

```
<Import Project="..\MyCustomTargets\custom.targets"/>
```

Inside that file I have a custom target (AfterBuild) which copies the compiled files to another location.

However, I'd like to add a reference path that each project can look to when trying to resolve references.  Is this possible?

For example, I'd like to add something like this to my .targets file:

```
<AdditionalReferencePath>C:\LookHereForReferences</AdditionalReferencePath>
```

I've found a few links that describe a little about how to do this but I can't get it working.

Comment: any update for this issue? Could you get useful information from the answer? If not, could you please let us to know the latest information about this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to add a reference path that each project can look to when trying to resolve references. Is this possible?

You can set a **Property Group** in your **.targets file**:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AdditionalReferencePath>C:\LookHereForReferences</AdditionalReferencePath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

After **import this targets file in to the project file**, you can look it by $(AdditionalReferencePath) when trying to resolve references:

```
  <Import Project="Common.targets" />
  <Target Name="Test" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="$(AdditionalReferencePath)"></Message>
  </Target>
```

[image]